# OnBeforeUnload not working when closing the window via cross button

Tags: javascript, window

onbeforeunload not working for the first time. But when I press ctrl+shift+t. It works correctly. Can anybody guide

I have tried the following code

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
      var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
      return message;
    }
  </script>
  <div>Hi</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Cross Icon]

Comment: What do you mean? you have to leave the page for it to run. Add a link on the page and click it

Comment: Also read this - some of the functionality is browser dependent https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: @mplungjan I want to have it run when I click the cross button on tab or close the browser itself.

Comment: Also NOTHING here is jQuery related. I changed your tags

Comment: Your code works in Chrome.

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry new here.

Comment: @mplungjan Did you tried clicking the close button or cross icon?

Comment: @mplungjan I have added the image link above. Kindly check I am having issue with tab close button and browser close button

Comment: If I click Run snippet, click full page, click [x] I get the message in chrome